# having trouble with texturing a roof

Tags: mesh, materials, uv

Hi could anyone help me with this roof? i am having trouble making it look good(Specifically applying the texture to it properly) any tips would be appreciated if the problem is with the way i modeled it then tell me what i could do differently.This model is for a game with the normal maps applied in engine it looks alot better with a dark realistic feel to it, but i am currently stuck on the roof this is my first time trying to model and texture a thatched roof of this sort.

Thanks,

[image][image]

Comment: You could probably start with a better underlying topology. Triangles are not very good for texturing. Also artistic help and critique is better suited for https://blenderartists.org, this site is more for technical help with Blender tools themselves

Comment: If you're not happy with any part of the roof you could allot each section it's own material slot and re-texture them independently, overlay parts with a patch etc.  You can also subdivide sections and do the same with those.

Comment: In texturing, the "nuclear option" is to use a different texture. The fact is, that some textures work better for some things than for others, and some combinations of mesh and texture just cannot be made to work at all, or at least not be made to work to my satisfaction.

Answer (score 3):

You could try re-doing the seams and unwrapping as in the images below so that you are using alot more of the texture.

[image]

When editing the UV islands you may find that you will need to flip one of them in the X axis (select island then sclae in the negative X axis, **S X -1** ) to get the red ties along the top to line up with each other.

[image]

Different Seams but again overlapping islands:
[image]